# Ubuntu 13.04 Wireless network adapter won't work (ASUS USB-N53)

Tags: networking, adapter

I just installed ubuntu on my brand new built computer.
I ended up buying ASUS USB-N53 network adapter for wifi but I cannot connect it to internet. I see few wifi selections but when I click on the wifi, it would only attempt to connect but fails.. please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the drivers from the manufacturer?

Asus:

http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN53/#support_Download_5

ASUS USB-N53 Driver 1.0.12.2 for Linux